# android device overrides flash mode when takePicture is called

Tags: android, flash, camera, torch

I have a strange problem with android phone iGet Blackview BV6000s. I need to set flash mode into torch mode during preview and actual photographing. Unfortunately it looks like, something is overriding my code and when takePicture is called, flash goes off and than behaves like regular flash.

Could it be something in that "custom" android, that device has preinstalled?

I made a minimum example beside my actual app and it behaves same.

preview setup:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    if(numCams > 0){
        try{
            camera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            }
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
            preview.setCamera(camera);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex){
            Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.camera_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

calling takePicture:

```
preview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    });
```